# Trouble calling functions with onClick and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

I'm trying to call a function when a radio button is clicked and I'm not sure why it won't work.

This works:

```
<input type="radio" onClick="alert();" />
```

But this for some reason does not:

```
<input type="radio" onClick="myFunction();" />

<script language="javascript">
function myFunction(){
    alert();
}
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/UeD47/), so your problem lies elsewhere, perhaps.

Comment: That throws up an error in FireBug too (Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindowInternal.alert]) - adding some parameters to the alert (alert('test');) works though.